# Input RC filter design for analog pin of ADC

Tags: filter

I am implementing ADC filter for AD7705 ( Sigma Delta ADC - Analog Devices Chip ). Input to ADC is constant DC voltage. So, what will be cut-off frequency I should consider to implement RC filter at analog input.

If we are designing RC filter, then by assuming C value ( typ 0.1uF ) and cut-off frequency above which we are trying to block signals (ripples) , we can calculate R value. Is this a approach which we consider for filter design? Am I correct in my consideration.

So for DC input at ADC pin, what should be ideal or practical cut-off frequency I should consider for designing RC filter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter how hard you try and convince yourself you have a dc input you'll be incorrect. If it were truly a dc input with no ac content then measuring the value once will be the same value as it is in 100 years time.

So, you have to consider how long it might take the signal to settle to "constant" when it is activated. If it is 1 second (say) then you need to consider that an RC filter having a time constant of 1 second is inappropriate. Most people assume the an RC filter settles to 99% in 5 time constants so in reality you might be looking at an RC filter with a cut-off of 5Hz: -

[image]

Maybe even ten time constants is more appropriate for your desired accuracy - this makes the filter a 10Hz low pass filter.

Comment: Nice elaborative answer!!!

But if there are two analog inputs switching through in-built MUX, is there need for considering this switching time. RC filter design considerations will be same in that case also?

Comment: If we consider Fcutoff=10Hz and C=0.1uF then R=1.6 K....so this high value of C ( 0.1uF) and R ( 1.6K) will have some impedance issue with input of ADC?

Comment: Not normally an issue. If you look at specs for (say) the PIC range of micros and what they recommend it would be no problem. Name your ADC and I'll show you.

Comment: I am using AD7705 ADC..here is link for datasheet: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7705_7706.pdf

Comment: @Electroholic it has an input current of 1nA max which means a dc measurement error thru 1k6 of 1.6 uV. Input capacitance of 10pF is swamped by the 100nF so no problem there either. Also if you look at table 22 it gives you some further options when selecting internal gain. Figure 14 also shows the typical input circuit inside the device to add further to demystification. Page 25 also mentions the use of a 10k resistor not causing a problem.

Comment: sorry typing mistake R = 160 k and C=0.1 uF @Andy aka

Comment: Nothing wrong with 16k and 1uF or 1k6 and 10uF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23433/discussion-between-electroholic-and-andy-aka).